# How can I modify the default test report output path of CTest?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, ctest

The default path for the test report generated by CTest is Testing/Temporary. I want to change the path.
I haven't found any way to modify this path yet. Does anyone know how to do it?

I want to manually set the test report path for CTest，generate different directories based on time.

1. directory tree

   ```bash
    .
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── main.c

    0 directories, 2 files
   ```
2. Source Code

   ```c
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(void) {
      printf("hello, world!\n");
      return 0;
   }
   ```
3. CmakeLists.txt File

   ```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

    # project name and language
    project(ctest VERSION 1.0
                  LANGUAGES C)

    set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER gcc)

    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror")

    add_executable(ctest_example main.c)

    # enable testing functionality
    enable_testing()

    # Test Group: media_to_maif_talker_stream0
    add_test(
      NAME ctest_example
      COMMAND sh -c "./ctest_example"
    )
   ```
4. Compile Command

   ```bash
   user: ~/ctest/$ cmake -S . -B ./out
   user: ~/ctest/$ cmake --build ./out
   user: ~/ctest/$ cd ./out
   user: ~/ctest/$  ctest
   ```
5. Question Description：

After running the ctest command, I will get a Testing/Temporary directory
under the out directory.

[ctest out directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVepR.png)

Can the path of Testing/Temporary be modified? If so, how should I set it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details how exactly you use `ctest`, how you configured CMake and how your directory structure looks like. Are the options `--output-log` or `--output-junit` related to your question?

Comment: Sorry, I have modified my question description, thank you very much for your response!

Comment: You could use a wrapper script that calls `ctest` and afterwards renames the directory `Testing/Temporary` according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the path of Testing/Temporary be modified?

Sure! Clone CMake, edit [the hardcoded "`/Testing/Temporary`" paths in the source code](https://gitlab.kitware.com/search?search=%2FTesting%2FTemporary&nav_source=navbar&project_id=541&group_id=415&search_code=true&repository_ref=master), build, and install your modified CMake, and then use that :)

See [the CMake README](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/README.rst) for instructions on building from scratch.

The above written happily with some jest. Obviously this is not a very ideal solution to the problem. If you want this to be more easily configurable, I'd suggest you [create a feature-request issue ticket](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/new) to the CMake maintainers asking for something like a [CTest variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html#variables-for-ctest) for this. An issue ticket has now been raised at https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/24845.